What to do with this detached garage entry door?
Our home has a stucco garage that’s probably 60+ years old. At some point one of the home owners retrofitted an entryway door to it that isn’t on top of the concrete slab.
The door has a huge gap (2”) underneath which lets rodents and tons of dust/dirt inside. Not to mention the actual door is only 31” wide.
How do I go about approaching a replacement like this so that this space can be properly sealed? I'd prefer to replace the door, but I’m not sure what to do about the fact that the wall and current door stick out over the flooring in the garage.
If adding a sill would work, I’d be on board for that cheaper solution, but again, it’s sticking out over some patio pavers.
Here are a few pics showing the door bottom and also where the door sill should be.



it's missing a threshold, but I'm not sure what the best way to fix that is.  are you concerned by the rotting wood?

@Jasen yeah, and it's hard to tell from photos, but it kinda looks like the surface is draining toward the door.

Buy a new pre-fab door and cut in a new frame to install it.
You probably have to put in new door framing if your existing door is a weird size.  This likely means cutting out the old frame and putting in a new one done right.  Depending on what that means you might need new siding, or you might just have to cut back the existing siding.  To do this yourself, watch some Youtube, there's so much great content out there for stuff like this.
It's not clear to me how you have a wall not on the foundation, but you will need a sill to mount on, either pour one with Quikrete and a wheelbarrow or put good pavers down.  If it freezes where you are you need guidance on what is needed, I've never owned a house where the ground freezes.
